# Can I safely delete my new Firebase project without losing my Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Started to add Firebase to my app. For that, I had to add SHA1 configuration but got this error

> An OAuth2 client already exists for this package name and SHA-1 in another project. You can omit the SHA-1 for now and [read more about this situation and how to resolve it](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008)

So I followed up [this linke](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6401008) as proposed and got to the instructions that seemed to be relevant to my case (i.e., starting to add Firebase to an existing app):

> If you just created this project or aren't very far into adding Firebase to your app, the simplest approach is to delete your project and instead import your existing Google project.

But, when I went ahead to delete my Firebase project, I got this scary message:

> This is a permanent action. All apps contained within this project will also be deleted.

My app is in production! I cannot delete it! Is this message written just from a Firebase console perspective? Can I be sure my existing app (originally defined in a regular Android project) will NOT be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation on my own realized the Firebase project can safely be deleted without loosing access to my original app. Here are the details.

- What's deleted is the corresponding GCP project (i.e., with same project ID); assuming you created a new project (which is what I did) - you'll get an automatically generated *new* GCP project and *it* will be deleted when you delete the new Firebase project.
- The GCP original GCP project which corresponds to my app (already on Google Play) is not touched.
- In case of a mistake, it's always possible to restore the original GCP project (see [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6251787?hl=en#)). I didn't need that but it was easier to decide to verify the above 2 bullets knowing this option exists.